# Spring - configure Jboss Intros for xml with java config?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

I'm in the process of writing a spring web app and want to convert my objects to xml without annotations. I know with xml config you can do this:

```
<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="software.bytepushers.userprofile.models.JaxbIntroductionsMarshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>software.bytepushers.userprofile.models.Person</value>
             <value>software.bytepushers.userprofile.models.WebServiceResponse</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jaxbContextProperties">
            <map>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                        <util:constant static-field="com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.ANNOTATION_READER"/>
                    </key>

                    <bean class="org.jboss.jaxb.intros.IntroductionsAnnotationReader">
                        <constructor-arg ref="jaxbIntroductions"/>
                    </bean>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="schema" value="classpath:schemas/avs-pdf-query-request.xsd"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jaxbIntroductions" class="org.jboss.jaxb.intros.IntroductionsConfigParser"
          factory-method="parseConfig">
        <constructor-arg><value>classpath:spring/jaxb-intros-marshaller-mapping.xml</value></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

In my webconfig.java right now I have

```
@Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() throws SAXException {
        org.springframework.core.io.Resource schema = new ClassPathResource("schemas/person-schema.xsd");

        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(new Class[]{Person.class});
        marshaller.setSchema(schema);

        return marshaller;
    }
```

I know I'm missing a lot in my java config, I'm new to java config and can't find a lot of documentation on how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is lack of documentation for a given item in xml config to java config, your best friend is to find the javadocs for the involved classes, in this case:

[@Bean javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html), [Jaxb2Marshaler javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.html), [JAXBRIContext javadoc](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/api/JAXBRIContext.html), and couldn't find the javadoc for IntroductionsConfigParser and IntroductionsAnnotationReader, maybe an active subscription to red hat is required? not sure about that.

I never used these classes myself, so perhaps there might be an error, but my first attempt would look like this:

```
@Bean(name = "jaxb2Marshaller")
public JaxbIntroductionsMarshaller jaxb2Marshaller() throws SAXException {
    JaxbIntroductionsMarshaller marshaller = new JaxbIntroductionsMarshaller ();

    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(new Class[] {
            Person.class,
            WebServiceResponse.class
        });

    Map<String,Object> jaxbContextProperties = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    jaxbContextProperties.put(JAXBRIContext.ANNOTATION_READER, introductionsAnnotationReader());
    marshaller.setJaxbContextProperties(jaxbContextProperties);

    Resource schema = new ClassPathResource("schemas/avs-pdf-query-request.xsd");
    marshaller.setSchema(schema);

    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public IntroductionsAnnotationReader introductionsAnnotationReader() {
    return new IntroductionsAnnotationReader(parseConfig());
}
```

Not exactly sure about factory-method right now, so i'll post my 2 possible options:

```
@Bean(name = "jaxbIntroductions") // bean id
public IntroductionsConfigParser parseConfig() { // factory-method
   return new IntroductionsConfigParser( /* classpath:spring/jaxb-intros-marshaller-mapping.xml, Resource or String?? lack of javadoc */ );
}
```

or

```
@Bean(name = "jaxbIntroductions") // bean id
public IntroductionsConfigParser parseConfig() {
   return IntroductionsConfigParser.parseConfig( /* Resource or String?? lack of javadoc */ );
}
```

Comment: I had to modify the jaxbIntroductions bean, but then it worked as is for me. Thanks for your help

Comment: As i pointed, couldn't find the javadoc API for jaxbIntroductions, so i had to just guess, glad it helped

Comment: for other users with the same issue: here is the jaxbIntros bean: 
`return IntroductionsConfigParser.parseConfig(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/spring/marshaller-mapping.xml"));`